# How to handle if scroll is under shadow dom using selenium web

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to handle if scroll is under shadow dom using selenium web

I need to scroll down and click on Continue button, i tried Actions class also and java script  executer also scroll to view method also. scrollIntoView() or Actions may not work directly. but if scroll the element manually means clicking the bottom of the continue button

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.